# Jenkins pipeline script with invoking powershell script file is not working in stages and gets hanged till i abort

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Hi am working on creating a descriptive pipeline which has 4 simple stages. Each stage steps is to invoke a powershell file with arguments.

```
pipeline{
agent none
    stages{
        stage("demo1"){
            steps{
                powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\file1.ps1 ${p1} ${p2} ${p3} ${p4} ${p5}" 
            }
        }
        stage("demo2"){
            steps{
                powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\file2.ps1 ${p1} ${p2} ${p3}" 
            }
        }
        stage("demo3"){
            steps{

                powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\file3.ps1 ${p1} ${p2} ${p3}" 
            }
        }
        stage("demo4"){
            steps{
                powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\file4.ps1 ${p1} ${p2} ${p3}"

            }
        }


    }
```

}

The pipeline starts successfully and completes 1st stage and moves to second stage. Once the second stage steps is completed, it is not further moving to the third step. In console output i am seeing a refresh symbol and the job status says in progress. Until i abort the job the still loading.

Please help me in resolving the issue and what is the resolution for this.

Comment: Are you sure that your powershell script determines?

Comment: Yes, when i run the powershell file as a separate instance  all are working and getting expected results.

Comment: Do you return an exit code in the script that gets stuck? If not you should give it a try. An exit code usually signalizes Jenkins that something has finished.

Comment: You meant to pass in the exit code in the jenkins pipeline steps ??

Comment: No, I mean whether you return an exit code in your script.

Comment: Yes we have the exit code

Comment: If your second powershell script starts  process that doesn’t end, then the Jenkins stage will never move to the next stage, such as launching an application server, it will wait indefinitely for the process to complete.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @DibakarAditya. I don't think the issue is happening onJenkins' side, rather the script does something wrong or is missing something.

Comment: @DibakarAditya I executed this steps in jenkins normal job which it moves further Only in pipeline this issue is faced

Comment: @mkemmerz I noticed one thing. On Random instance of 10, i am able to see that 3 execution pipeline moves to next stage remaining 7 it keeps on waiting in same stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Guys thanks for all your support in making this issue resolved. As @mkemmerz and @DibakarAditya mentioned, all process has to be completed to proceed further. In my case winniumdriver process is still on, thats the reason jenkins is not moving to next stage. Added a command to kill the process. Working perfectly